# Why return !!var JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

After looking at Sizzle.js I noticed they have an assert function (see below) which returns `!!fn(x)`.

Why would anyone do that? It seems pointless to do that as it would just be `"not not"`.

```
function assert( fn ) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  try {
    return !!fn( div );
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  } finally {
    // release memory in IE
    div = null;
  }
}
```

Anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: AFAIK it is a way to "cast" to boolean, but maybe someone with more insight to this can elaborate more..

Comment: Sorry I did have a look for another question simular but couldn't find it, it probably is a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sure the return type is boolean and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just tested that as well. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There's no `bool` in JavaScript, boolean is more appropriate